# API requesting same info repeatedly

Tags: javascript, api

CODE:
      var j = 0;

```
  function loadDesigns(j){
  // Create XHR Object [dont forget to add 'new']
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", 'http://www.pat-cooney.com/gd.json', true);

  xhr.onload = function(){
    if (this.status == 200) {
      var designs = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      var contentOutput = "";
      var contentImages = "";
      var galleryNavOutput = "";

      function addImageNav() {
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          galleryNavOutput += '<img id="' + designs[i].classId + '"src="' + designs[i].thumbnail + '">'
        }
      };

      function addContentImages() {
          contentImages += '<img src="' + designs[j].images[0] + '">';
      };

      contentOutput +=
      '<div class="block2">' +
          '<div id="inner">'+
              addContentImages() +
          '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="row">' +
          '<div id="center">' +
              addImageNav() +
          '</div>' +
      '</div>';

      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = contentOutput;
      document.getElementById("inner").innerHTML = contentImages;
      document.getElementById("center").innerHTML = galleryNavOutput;
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}
loadDesigns(j);

//.3 sec delay to allow AJAX delivery
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", function(){
    setTimeout(function() {loadDesigns(0);},300);
  });
  document.getElementById("two").addEventListener("click", function(){
    setTimeout(function() {loadDesigns(1);},300);
  });
  document.getElementById("three").addEventListener("click", function(){
    setTimeout(function() {loadDesigns(2);},300);
  });
}, 300);
```

Here is a codepen with the code being used: https://codepen.io/Pcooney13/pen/wpXyvX note it does not load the images due to codepen rules about API’s so here is the code semi-working: http://www.pat-cooney.com/example.html

in the /example.html I can click any of the bottom 3 images and it updates the top image. My problem is that it only works once and then I have to refresh the page.

I am using the same xhr request to the same small source multiple times, is this bad? can I store this info in the first request then continue to use it without having to call it every time a user clicks? 2. using ids for the bottom images could be interfering each request?

Im using vanilla JS, Any help would be greatly appreciated and sorry for the frankenstein sourcing

Comment: `//.3 sec delay to allow AJAX delivery` Never do that! You have an `onload` callback for your Ajax call already; inside the callback is where you know the data is ready. An arbitrary timeout will either (1) cause an unnecessary delay if the server responds faster, or (2) cause you to miss the data entirely if the server takes longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is this:
You attach your click handlers to certain elements. Then when you click on that element you remove it from the page and add another element with the same id. These new elements with the same id don't have a click handler on them anymore. A better way to do it would be to put the click handler on the `body` and look at the id of what element was clicked. If it was one of your desired elements then you would execute the ajax call.

The reason this works is because the body is never being removed and re-added to the page. An alternate solution would be to add your event handlers back onto the newly created elements.

Restructuring your code a bit (simplifying some things though this can be simplified more) and building a working solution would give you this:

```
function loadDesigns(j){
  // Create XHR Object [dont forget to add 'new']
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", 'http://www.pat-cooney.com/gd.json', true);

  xhr.onload = function(){
  if (this.status == 200) {
      var designs = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

      function addImageNav() {
          var galleryNavOutput = "";
          for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
              galleryNavOutput += '<img id="' + designs[i].classId + '"src="' + designs[i].thumbnail + '">'
          }
          return galleryNavOutput;
      }

      function addContentImages() {
          return '<img src="' + designs[j].images[0] + '">';
      }

      contentOutput =
      '<div class="block2">' +
          '<div id="inner">'+
              addContentImages() +
          '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="row">' +
          '<div id="center">' +
              addImageNav() +
          '</div>' +
      '</div>';

      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = contentOutput;
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}
loadDesigns(0);

document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  switch (e.target.id) {
    case 'one':
      loadDesigns(0);
      break;
    case 'two':
      loadDesigns(1);
      break;
    case 'three':
      loadDesigns(2);
      break;
    default:
       return;
  }
});
```

I should also note that this pattern of concatenating strings to build DOM is dangerous and a better approach would be to create the elements individually (`document.createElement`) and adding the attributes on with getters and setters. When you concatenate strings to build DOM (in particular strings you don't control - ie user input) you open yourself up to [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) whereby an attacker can run their own JS on your page.

Comment: Thank you the above code worked, and I will look into alternatives using (document.createElement) instead of concatenating.